# How use no-cors with fetch()

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, fetch, response

I have a problem. I try to explain it.

My client ask me to build a web portal for fetching and modifying data on private server, with Basic Auth.

The private server return a XML files.

I try using fetch() to get the data but I have a CORS error. I know what that mean but I don't have the hand on the private server.

So I would like use my fetch() with :

```
mode : 'no-cors'
```

but if I use like that, I can use the data fetched.

I think I have 2 main solutions:

- Add CORS support to the API you are using. This only works if you have control over the target.
- Instead of making the request from your domain, something else needs to make the request for you.

If I can’t add CORS headers, I will likely want to build a small server-side script that can make these requests on my behalf.

Instead of calling the target directly, my script can now call my script, which has to do the request for you server-side.

But, if I don't have the hands on the server, how can I do that ?

If someone have an idea...

Thanks a lot...

---- EDIT -----

My code :

```
getListApps: async function () {

            let url = `${SA_BASE_URL}/applications`;

            // Set headers
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(SA_LOGIN + ":" + SA_PASSWORD));
            try {
                // GET request
                const response = await fetch(url, { 
                    method: 'GET', 
                    headers: headers, 
                    mode: 'no-cors', 
                    credentials: 'include' })

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    this.listApp = data;
                    this.listApp.forEach(app => {
                        if (app.status === "DISCONNECTED") {
                            this.listDecApp.push(app);
                        }
                    });
                    this.nbr = this.listDecApp.length;
                } else {
                    if (response.status === 400) this.errors = ['Invalid app_permissions value. (err.400)'];
                    if (response.status === 401) this.errors = ['Acces denied. (err.401)'];
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                this.errors = ["Une erreur est survenue lors de la récupération des informations sur le serveur."]
            }
            
        },
```

Comment: see my answer below. if no-cors shows an opaque response then cors should work.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use no-cors, set it in the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers), like:

```js
var opts = {
  headers: {
    'mode':'cors'
  }
}
fetch(url, opts)
```

If you do not control the API, there is little you can do.

Comment: Thanks but I already doing this. Unfortunatlly, it seems I can't use the content of the response if I use no-cors mode. And I would like use it...

Comment: @JoLeBelge can you post a code example of what you are already doing?

Comment: @JoLeBelge also, can you try running `curl <api link>` on your terminal and see if you receive a valid response?

Comment: I update my post. And I can't use curl because I don't have access at the private server.

Comment: @JoLeBelge if you dont have access then you cannot fetch this api.

Comment: Yes, I know but my client have the access, of course...

Comment: @JoLeBelge If your client has access, then you should be able to ask them for authentication and include it in the headers. Why are you asking us?

Comment: I asking about how can I fetch data with browser on a remote server if this one don't have a "allow-cross-origin"

Comment: You cannot. That is why I asked you if cURL works.

Comment: mode is not HTTP header, it goes directly in opts. But `cors` is the default value, so above code is equivalent to just `fetch(url)`.

Comment: mode should not be inside headers: this is a property of the highest level of nesting. Look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options